# how to click on a button after popup windows loaded completely

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to click on some html element pragmatically.
I use Jquery selector to select a button and click it.

`$('span.firstBtn').click();`

after clicking this button a popup window will show and then I want to click a button in the popup windows.

`$('div.BtnOnPopupWindows').click();`

but I get null pointer because there is no popup windows when code run. so i need to wait till completion of loading the popup window. how can I do this? how can I wait till completion of loading of the popup window?

Answer (score 4):

Use the jQuery's `.on()` method with [delegated event handlers](https://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events):

```js
// DELEGATED EVENT HANDLERS
// Delegate event for existing or future elements using .on() with delegation:
$(document).on("click", ".BtnOnPopupWindows", function() {
  console.log("BtnOnPopupWindows CLICK");
});

// DIRECT EVENT HANDLERS
// Define button click:
$('.firstBtn').on("click", function() {
  console.log("firstBtn CLICK")
  $('#popup').html(`<div class="BtnOnPopupWindows">TEST</div>`);
});

// Dynamically trigger stuff
$('.firstBtn').click();
$('.BtnOnPopupWindows').click();
```

```html
<span class="firstBtn">BUTTON</span>
<div id="popup"><!--will be dynamically populated--></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Tip: Instead of using `$(document)` try always to delegate to a first static (non-dynamic) Element parent. For the above example it would be like:

```
// Static parent - on click - dynamic child
$("#popup").on("click", ".BtnOnPopupWindows", function() {
```

Comment: Thank you Roko, but I don't have access to change event handlers of the buttons. Consider that I have a form to complete and send programmatically. I click a button and it will popup a window for me. I need to click a button on the puped up window too and  need to wait till full loading of it.

Comment: @mehdi popup? Window? Iframe? What? Hmm... if you don't have access to that popup website there's not much you can do unless it's in your Domain name. Imagine you controlled a popup of my bank account... Do you get the idea? I would wonder for years why a hacker stranger gave me 1m € :D

Comment: Consider that I am developing a robot for autofilling of some forms. After clicking send button a popup emergs and ask me to confirm my decision. I want to wait till end of the loading of the popup and then click on the confirm button. It has nothing to do with hack.

Comment: @mehdi seems I need to ask again,.. is that "window" page on your domain? Or it's someone's else website?

Comment: it is not my website and I just want to fill and submit some forms automatically.

Comment: @mehdi you cannot do that. And what you're trying to do is called phishing. Read again my previous comment.

Comment: it is not phishing. it is just filling and submitting some forms. by the way i found a way.